# ansible.builtin.uri module - Read and format JSON file content as a string to use in payload

Tags: json, ansible, uri

I am trying to use the [ansible.builtin.lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) plugin in order to read a JSON file from the local directory and then pass it as the payload to the [ansible.builtin.uri](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html) module to send a POST message to a URI endpoint.

Following are the contents of my JSON file (*config.json*):

```json
    {
      "Configuration": {
        "Components": [
          {
            "Name": "A",
            "Attributes": [
              {
                "Name": "A1",
                "Value": "1",
                "Set On Import": "True",
                "Comment": "Read and Write"
              },
              {
                "Name": "A2",
                "Value": "2",
                "Set On Import": "True",
                "Comment": "Read and Write"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I need to send the above JSON content as the below string in the payload to ansible.builtin.uri module:

```
"{\"Configuration\": {\"Components\": [{\"Name\": \"A\", \"Attributes\": [{\"Name\": \"A1\", \"Value\": \"1\", \"Set On Import\": \"True\", \"Comment\": \"Read and Write\"}, {\"Name\": \"A2\", \"Value\": \"2\", \"Set On Import\": \"True\", \"Comment\": \"Read and Write\"}]}]}}"
```

I am trying to use the lookup plugin with the [to_json](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) filter to read and format the JSON content. Following is my playbook:

```
- name: import scp
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://{{ inventory_hostname }}/api/config/actions/import"
    user: "{{ user }}"
    password: "{{ password }}"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Accept: "application/json"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    body:
      Parameters:
        Type: "LOCAL_FILE"
        Target: "ALL"
        IgnoreCertificateWarning: "Enabled"
      Buffer: "{{ lookup('file', 'config.json') | to_json }}"
    body_format: json
    status_code: 202
    validate_certs: no
    force_basic_auth: yes
```

However, the uri module double escapes all the new-line and tab characters. Following is the how the payload is sent when I run the playbook:

```
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "body": {
                "Buffer": "\"{\\n\\t\\\"Configuration\\\": {\\n\\t\\t\\\"Components\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Name\\\": \\\"A\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Attributes\\\": [\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Name\\\": \\\"A1\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Value\\\": \\\"1\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Set On Import\\\": \\\"True\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Comment\\\": \\\"Read and Write\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t},\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t{\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Name\\\": \\\"A2\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Value\\\": \\\"2\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Set On Import\\\": \\\"True\\\",\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\\"Comment\\\": \\\"Read and Write\\\"\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t]\\n\\t\\t\\t}\\n\\t\\t]\\n\\t}\\n}\"",
                "Parameters": {
                    "IgnoreCertificateWarning": "Enabled",
                    "Type": "LOCAL_FILE",
                    "Target": "ALL"
                },
            },
            "body_format": "json",
...
    },
```

Could you please let me know how I can format the payload with uri module? Appreciate any help.

**Edited (5/11/2021):**
I made the changes as suggested by @mdaniel in his response and used `string` filter instead of `to_json`. With the suggested change, I can see the JSON being formatted properly into a string with newline ('\n') and tab ('\t') characters. I tried to use the `replace` filter to remove the `\n` and `\t` characters. However, now the whole string is converted back into the JSON.

Following is the playbook and the output when using the `string` filter alone:

```
...
        body:
          Parameters:
            Type: "LOCAL_FILE"
            Target: "ALL"
            IgnoreCertificateWarning: "Enabled"
          Buffer: "{{ lookup('file', 'config.json') | string }}"
```

```
$ ansible-playbook import_file.yml -i hosts --tags

...
            "body": {
                "HostPowerState": "On",
                "Buffer": "{\n\t\"Configuration\": {\n\t\t\"Components\": [\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\"Name\": \"A\",\n\t\t\t\t\"Attributes\": [\n\t\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Name\": \"A1\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Value\": \"1\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Set On Import\": \"True\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Comment\": \"Read and Write\"\n\t\t\t\t\t},\n\t\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Name\": \"A2\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Value\": \"2\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Set On Import\": \"True\",\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\"Comment\": \"Read and Write\"\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t]\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t]\n\t}\n}",
                "Parameters": {
                    "IgnoreCertificateWarning": "Enabled",
                    "Type": "LOCAL_FILE",
                    "Target": "ALL"
                },
            },
```

Following is the playbook and the output when using `replace` filter in conjunction with `string` filter:

```
...
        body:
          Parameters:
            Type: "LOCAL_FILE"
            Target: "ALL"
            IgnoreCertificateWarning: "Enabled"
          Buffer: "{{ lookup('file', 'config.json') | string | replace('\n', '') | replace('\t', '') }}"
...
```

```
$ ansible-playbook import_file.yml -i hosts --tags

...
            "body": {
                "Buffer":  {
                    "Configuration": {
                        "Components": [
                            {
                                "Attributes": [
                                    {
                                        "Comment": "Read and Write",
                                        "Name": "A1",
                                        "Set On Import": "True",
                                        "Value": "1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Comment": "Read and Write",
                                        "Name": "A2",
                                        "Set On Import": "True",
                                        "Value": "2"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "Name": "A"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "Parameters": {
                    "IgnoreCertificateWarning": "Enabled",
                    "Type": "LOCAL_FILE",
                    "Target": "ALL"
                },
            },
...
```

Any pointers on how I remove the `\n` and `\t` characters from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `to_json` on a `dict` value that is, itself, going to be `to_json`-ed; ansible cannot transmit a python `dict` over HTTP, so any yaml structure that is not already a string needs to be converted into one first

What you'll want is just that lookup result (which will return a `str`, not a `dict`) and then ansible will apply `to_json` to the whole `body:` value for the aforementioned reason

However, because ansible is trying to be "helpful", it will auto-coerce a yaml value that it finds starting with `{` *back* into a `dict` -- that's why you just need to send the result of `lookup` through the `| string` filter to reinforce to ansible that yes, you really do want it to remain a `str` in that context

```yaml
...

    body:
      Parameters:
        Type: "LOCAL_FILE"
        Target: "ALL"
        IgnoreCertificateWarning: "Enabled"
      Buffer: "{{ lookup('file', 'config.json') | string }}"
```

---

*updated answer approach*

In light of the comment discussion that the `dict` coercion was continuing to be a problem, and the leading space concerned the OP, the alternative approach is to build up the actual payload structure completely, and only "JSON-ify" it before transmission, to keep ansible and jinja on the same page about the data types:

```yaml
- name: import scp
  vars:
    body_dict:
      Parameters:
        Type: "LOCAL_FILE"
        Target: "ALL"
        IgnoreCertificateWarning: "Enabled"
      # this will be filled in before submission
      # Buffer:
    whitespace_free_config_json: >-
          {{ lookup('file', 'config.json') 
          | regex_replace('[\t\n]', '')
          | string
          }}
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    ...
    body: >-
      {{ body_dict
      | combine({"Buffer": whitespace_free_config_json})
      | to_json }}
    body_format: json
    status_code: 202
```

Comment: thanks for your very prompt response and a great explanation. I tried your recommendation and now I can see ansible formatting the JSON into a string with newline ('\n') and tab ('\t') characters. I tried using replace filter on the string like "{{ lookup('file', 'config.json') | string | replace('\n', '') | replace('\t', '') }}", however it again converted the whole string into a JSON again. Any poniters?

Comment: For clarity, the `| string` happened at the end of the pipeline to prevent ansible from coercing the `{` looking string to a dict -- it is already a string when leaving the `lookup()` call; that said, it seems that for some horrible reason using more pipeline steps now ignores the `| string` at the end and coerces it back to a `dict` anyway; the best work-around I have is `Buffer: "{{ ' ' + (lookup(...) | ...) }}"` to stop the coercion via a leading space :-(

Comment: Thanks @mdaniels. It seems we are getting there :-). I tried your workaround and now I am getting the string that I wanted. Only thing left remaining to do now is to remove the leading whitespace from the begining of the string. I tried using the ```Buffer: {{ ' ' + lookup('file', 'config.json') | string | trim | ... }}``` filter, but it does not remove the leading whitespace. What could I be missing here?

Comment: Well, that's the _problem_; the leading space is there on purpose (it's not an accident, as one can see by my use of a string literal concatenation. If your upstream service cares that much about a leading space in a JSON payload, that's for sure weird, but as it similarly is for them to care about tab characters and newlines. Anywho, the only other knob I have is to build up the _entire_ `body:` payload as a dict, and `to_json` it yourself; I didn't include that in my answer because it's usually more effort, but if you care about one space, then maybe I'll show it

Comment: thank you so much for your help and being patient with me :-) IThis completely works !!